# Python Subprocess readline() hangs; can't use normal options

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess

To start, I'm aware this looks like a duplicate.  I've been reading:

[Python subprocess readlines() hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12419198/python-subprocess-readlines-hangs)

[Python Subprocess readline hangs() after reading all input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40963927/python-subprocess-readline-hangs-after-reading-all-input)

[subprocess readline hangs waiting for EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897202/subprocess-readline-hangs-waiting-for-eof)

But these options either straight don't work or I can't use them.

## The Problem

```
# Obviously, swap HOSTNAME1 and HOSTNAME2 with something real
cmd = "ssh -N -f -L 1111:<HOSTNAME1>:80 <HOSTNAME2>"

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, env=os.environ)
while True:
    out = p.stdout.readline()
    # Hangs here ^^^^^^^ forever

    out = out.decode('utf-8')
    if out:
        print(out)
    if p.poll() is not None:
        break
```

My dilemma is that the function calling the `subprocess.Popen()` is a library function for running bash commands, so it needs to be very generic and has the following restrictions:

- Must display output as it comes in; not block and then spam the screen all at once
- Can't use multiprocessing in case the parent caller is multiprocessing the library function (Python doesn't allow child processes to have child processes)
- Can't use `signal.SIGALRM` for the same reason as multiprocessing; the parent caller may be trying to set their own timeout
- Can't use third party non-built-in modules
- Threading straight up doesn't work.  When the `readline()` call is in a thread, `thread.join(timeout=1)`lets the program continue, but **ctrl+c** doesn't work on it at all, and calling `sys.exit()` doesn't exit the program, since the thread is still open.  And as you know, you can't kill a thread in python by design.
- No manner of bufsize or other subprocess args seems to make a difference; neither does putting readline() in an iterator.

I would have a workable solution if I could **kill a thread**, but that's super taboo, even though this is definitely a legitimate use case.

I'm open to any ideas.

Comment: (Those would be host names, not URLs.)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I finally got a working solution; the key piece of information I was missing was **`thread.daemon = True`**, which @augurar pointed out in their answer.

Setting `thread.daemon = True` allows the thread to be terminated when the main process terminates; therefore unblocking my use of a sub-thread to monitor `readline()`.

Here is a sample implementation of my solution; I used a `Queue()` object to pass strings to the main process, and I implemented a 3 second timer for cases like the original problem I was trying to solve where the subprocess has finished and terminated, but the readline() is hung for some reason.

This also helps avoid a race condition between which thing finishes first.

This works for both Python 2 and 3.

```
import sys
import threading
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime

try:
    import queue
except:
    import Queue as queue # Python 2 compatibility


def _monitor_readline(process, q):
    while True:
        bail = True
        if process.poll() is None:
            bail = False
        out = ""
        if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
            out = process.stdout.readline().decode('utf-8')
        else:
            out = process.stdout.readline()
        q.put(out)
        if q.empty() and bail:
            break

def bash(cmd):
    # Kick off the command
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)

    # Create the queue instance
    q = queue.Queue()
    # Kick off the monitoring thread
    thread = threading.Thread(target=_monitor_readline, args=(process, q))
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
    start = datetime.now()
    while True:
        bail = True
        if process.poll() is None:
            bail = False
            # Re-set the thread timer
            start = datetime.now()
        out = ""
        while not q.empty():
            out += q.get()
        if out:
            print(out)

        # In the case where the thread is still alive and reading, and
        # the process has exited and finished, give it up to 3 seconds
        # to finish reading
        if bail and thread.is_alive() and (datetime.now() - start).total_seconds() < 3:
            bail = False
        if bail:
            break

# To demonstrate output in realtime, sleep is called in between these echos
bash("echo lol;sleep 2;echo bbq")
```

Comment: Can you explain how this is different from @augurar's answer above?

Comment: Yes, primarily it actually runs as opposed to your code sketch, and it solves a race condition problem present in your sketch that causes output to be cut off randomly when the subprocess is done executing but the output isn't finished being read.  Try your implementation locally with some ssh commands or a curl GET call.  Also, I'm not sure why you need to tag yourself in your own comment?

Comment: I want to help future readers of the question find the correct answer rather than this answer which is overly specific to your use case.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use a thread to publish to a queue.  Then you can block on the queue with a timeout.  You can make the reader thread a daemon so it won't prevent system exit.  Here's a sketch:

```
import subprocess
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue

def reader(stream, queue):
    while True:
        line = stream.readline()
        queue.put(line)
        if not line:
            break

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, ...)
queue = Queue()
thread = Thread(target=reader, args=(p.stdout, queue))
thread.daemon = True
thread.start()
while True:
    out = queue.get(timeout=1)  # timeout is optional
    if not out:  # Reached end of stream
        break
    ...  # Do whatever with output

# Output stream was closed but process may still be running
p.wait()
```

Note that you should adapt this answer to your particular use case. For example, you may want to add a way to signal to the reader thread to stop running before reaching the end of stream.

Another option would be to poll the input stream, like in this question: [timeout on subprocess readline in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756383/timeout-on-subprocess-readline-in-python)

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer; the piece I was missing was knowing about the `daemon` flag.  For some reason, you can't specify it in the Thread() initialization, you have to do `thread.daemon = True` after the fact.

Comment: @Locane `daemon` is a keyword-only argument to `Thread()` in Python 3, in Python 2 you have to set it via a property before calling `thread.start()`.

Comment: Thanks @augurar, it seems to be working with `thread.daemon = True` in either version for me

Comment: Yes, if you need to support Python 2 then that's the way to go.