# Python subprocess.run does not return a string as stdout when calling "git remote"

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I am making a program to show git remotes, but this code just returns `b''`

```
>>> subprocess.run(
...                 "git remote",
...                 capture_output=True,
...                 shell=True,
...                 cwd=r'\Users\Andy\source\repos\PyPlus', stdout=subprocess.PIPE
...                 ).stdout
```

I also tried this, and this also returns `b''`:

```
>>> subprocess.run(
...                 "git remote",
...                 shell=True,
...                 cwd=r'\Users\Andy\source\repos\PyPlus', stdout=subprocess.PIPE
...                 ).stdout
```

In PowerShell, this command works.

```
PS C:\Users\Andy\source\repos\PyPlus> git remote
origin
```

So why this does not work? Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61956345/how-to-interact-with-an-external-program-in-python-3/61956620#61956620

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with the code shown. Both approaches (the first needs removing ``stdout`` to not fail with ``ValueError``) correctly return ``b'origin\n'`` in a git repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested this in a random directory and it seems like the return goes into stderr instead of stdout. So this worked:

```
test = subprocess.run("git remote", shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).stderr
>>> test
b'fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git\n'
```

Edit:
tested it in a git repository folder and your explained code worked for me:

```
test = subprocess.run("git remote", shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
>>> test
b'origin\n'
```

Maybe another solution which works for you:

```
import os

test = os.popen("git remote").read()
```

Comment: When the directory is not random but in fact a git repository, the output does *not* got to stderr but instead to stdout. That ``fatal`` error goes to stderr is to be expected, but not the use-case of the question.

Comment: youre right - works as intended. I think the comment from @PSKP is more suitable anyway

Comment: Got it. I’ll change the cwd attribute.